# Redirect Connections to a SQL Instance

Tags: sql-server, connections

I have a LAN in which clients connect to the SQL Server installed on a server with the IP address of 192.168.1.10 (`SERVER_A`).

I have another SQL Server instance installed on another server with the IP address of 192.168.3.11 (`SERVER_B`).

The servers are routed to each other so I can connect to one instance by SSMS from the other server.

The problem is I need to connect from the clients in the LAN (192.168.1.0) to the instance installed on `SERVER_B`.

Is there a way to create an alias instance on `SERVER_A` which points to the instance installed on `SERVER_B`? So I can connect to `SERVER_A` and it redirects me to `SERVER_B`?

I have an application and I can't change how it talks to the database. So I have to create all the Tables, Views and SPs again on `SERVER_A` and redirect them to tables, views, and SPs on `SERVER_B`. I want to use something like aliasing. However the problem is I can connect to the instance locally but not remotely when I use alias instance name.

Comment: So to clarify the issue is that clients are *not* routed to the SERVER_B (.3 subnet) but ARE routed to Server_A.  As a result, you are trying to avoid a network routing request to allow them to filter to Server_B *THROUGH* Server_A?

Comment: Or is the issue that you don't want clients to change their connection strings, so you'd rather them keep the same string but then automatically connect to the new server?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a linked server on `SERVER_A` to `SERVER_B` and access the databases using four part naming (`SERVER_B.database.schema.table`). See [How to Create a Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx) in the documentation.

You can also just add a secondary IP address to `SERVER_B`.

If `Server_B` is on the same VLAN as `Server_A`, you can add an alias to its IP address at the client level. But what you want to do is not very feasible.